# Returning subset of roles from a user in ADFS query

Tags: active-directory, ldap, adfs

So I have the something like the following LDAP query I'm trying to add into and ADFS custom claims rule.

(memberOf=CN=Parent_group,OU=Child_group1,OU=Child_group1,DC=Development)

Parent_group contains all the groups I am interested in (Child_group1, Child_group2), the child groups hold the roles I want.

My current ADFS rule returns all roles under the user trying to login

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"), query = ";tokenGroups;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

Can I combine these to only provide a subset of roles the user has?

EDIT:
Just to expand on the answer below this is what I ended up with:
I used two rules, one to get the distinguished name and a second uses the distinguished name to get the groups I want

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.com/identity/distinguishedName"), query = "; distinguishedName;{0}", param = c.Value);


c:[Type == "http://schemas.com/identity/distinguishedName"] && c2:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.com/groups/"), query = "(&(memberOf=CN=Parent_group,OU=Child_groups1,OU=Child_groups2,DC=domain,DC=company,DC=ROOT)(member={0}));CN;{1}", param = c.Value, param = c2.Value);
```

{0} uses the distinguished name to pare down the query to only the groups involved with the user.
{1} uses the windows account name so I don't have to hard code the domain/user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom rule i.e. something like:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
=> issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://company.com/claim"), query = "(&(objectClass=user) (memberof=CN=Parent_group,OU=Child_group1,OU=Child_group1,DC=Development));mail;domain\user", param = c.Value);

**Update**

The format of the query is described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-help-attribute-stores(WS.10).aspx) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pinch-perfect/2015/09/14/querying-attributes-from-active-directory-using-adfs-with-a-3rd-party-identity-provider/).

No - you can remove "&(objectClass=user)" if you want.

"domain\user" is required as per the articles. The only important part is the domain. You can put any string for the user.

Comment: You seem to be the only one answering these ADFS questions! I'm a little confused about your answer, specifically two sections: &(objectClass=user) is this something I need to put in or is it something that needs to change depending on my needs? ;mail;domain\user same question as above.